# Can not deploy Google Apps Script API Executable using clasp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api, clasp

I am using clasp to operate Google Apps Script with CLI.
Now I want to create a new version and deploy it as API executable.
So I have tried to run the following command by referring to the link below.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp

`clasp push` (-> I can find that my local change is reflected in the GAS project.)
`clasp version` (-> I can find that the new version is created)
`clasp deploy -V` ${version num whose created in previous command} (-> it seems not to deploy)

Then I got the following message when I try to run the GAS project via API:

```
code: 404,
errors: [
    {
      message: 'Requested entity was not found.',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'notFound'
    }
]
```

Is it possible to deploy as API executable using the `clasp deploy` command?
If it is possible, could you please tell me the correct way to deploy using CLI?

Comment: Try `clasp versions` before `clasp deploy -V` and see if the version is present?

Comment: When you created the clasp project what type of GAS project did you select? Is it linked to a GCP project? Can you view the deployment in the UI from `File > Manage versions...`?